# I want to make a Shiny app but I keep getting an error saying that an object can't be located

Tags: r, shiny, choropleth

It says "Error: Cannot open "Zipcodes_Poly"; The file doesn't seem to exist." The object is in my global environment and my working directory is properly set. Moreover, the code runs when I make a choropleth with the same object. I want to convert it into a shiny app in a script titled "server.R" but it keeps crashing. What could I be doing wrong?

```
#-----------------------------------#
# Server Script                     #                           
#                                   #
#-----------------------------------#

# This is the server logic for a Shiny web application.
# You can find out more about building applications with Shiny here:
#
# http://shiny.rstudio.com
#

#------------------------------------
# Beginning Shiny Code
#------------------------------------

# This line begins the shiny app


#-------------------------
# Maps
#-------------------------

 # Use these coordinates to center the map
# Load the required libraries
library(dplyr)
library(sf)
library(leaflet)

shinyServer(function(input, output) {

 # Read in the datasets
Zipcodes_Poly <- read_sf("Zipcodes_Poly")
place_data <- read.csv("place_data.csv")

# Create a grouping variable for the Risk column in place_data
place_data$group <- cut(place_data$Risk, 
                        breaks = c(0, 25, 50, 75, 100), 
                        labels = c("0-24", "25-49", "50-74", "75-98"))

# Perform a left join on the datasets based on the zip code
place_data$CODE <- as.character(place_data$CODE)
zip_merge <- left_join(Zipcodes_Poly, place_data, by = "CODE")

# Create the popup for each zip code polygon
zip_popup <- paste("<strong>Zip Code:", as.character(zip_merge$CODE),
                   "<br>",
                   "<br>Risk Index:<br>",
                   as.character(zip_merge$Risk),
                   "<br>Poverty:",
                   zip_merge$Poverty,
                   "<br>Education:",
                   zip_merge$Education,
                   "<br>Unemployment:",
                   zip_merge$Unemployment,
                   "<br>Crime:",
                   zip_merge$Crime,
                   "<br>ACEs:",
                   zip_merge$ACEs)

# Color the zip code polyggons based on the grouping variable
nicecolors <- colorFactor(c("#FBDA93", "#F39953", "#DF5258", "#C63542"),
                          zip_merge$group)

# Create the leaflet map object
map <- leaflet(Zipcodes_Poly) %>% 
  fitBounds(-124, 34, -62, 40) %>%
  addProviderTiles("CartoDB.Positron") %>%
  addPolygons(stroke = TRUE, smoothFactor = 0.2, fillOpacity = .8,
              color = ~nicecolors(group))
              

# output the map
 output$map <- renderLeaflet(map)

 })
```

I tried organizing my files and redownloaded all the files from scratch. Still doesn't work.

Comment: How exactly is your project currently structured? Is this just your `server.R` file? Do you have a `global.R` file? Do you have any folders? What command are you running to start your app? Are you also sure the file doesn't have a file extension at all?

Comment: Are you sure you have to call your variable with `""` ? Is your shiny app at the root of your working directory ?

Comment: I know you say that the working directory is properly set, but ... all too often questions about "shiny" and "file not found" are because the working-directory is counter-intuitively something else. I suggest for troubleshooting you include `message("WD=", getwd())` immediately before the `read_sf`, both locally and in your "deployed" state, and confirm that you're right about it, or find out that it's not quite what you think.